# Fixture inheritance in django TestCase

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a very simple scenario

```
from django.test import TestCase

class BaseTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ('users.json',)
    ...


class SpecificTest(BaseTest):
    fixtures = ('transactions.json',)
    ...
```

transactions has an FK to users and when SpecificTest attempts to load the fixtures I get an `IntegrityError`

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: 
The row in table 'app_transactions' with primary key '1' has an 
invalid foreign key: app_transactions.user_id contains a value '30'   
that does not have a corresponding value in app_user.id.
```

This error means that the `users.json` fixture loaded in `BaseTest` was not loaded before the `transactions.json` fixtures (as you might expect). My question is, what is the proper way to load fixtures when subclassing tests ?

Django 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you override `fixtures` in a subclass, it *replaces* the fixtures, it doesn't extend them.

You can either explicitly repeat the fixtures:

```
class SpecificTest(BaseTest):
    fixtures = ('users.json', 'transactions.json',)
```

or refer to `BaseTest.fixtures` in your subclass:

```
class SpecificTest(BaseTest):
    fixtures = BaseTest.fixtures + ('transactions.json',)
```

Comment: So you basically cant use mixins in tests if you use fixtures ?

Comment: You can use mixins in test cases, but it won't take care of loading the fixtures in the way that you are hoping.

Comment: Fixtures can be a real pain to work with and get stale very fast, esp during testing. Instead, I use Factory Boy: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, this is very disappointing. I though of just loading the fixtures in the setUp my self using `exeucte_command`. Thanks for the recommendation @Brandon.

Comment: You're welcome. I've had a lot of success with FactoryBoy.

Comment: @haki you might be able to get it to work in `setUp`, but you're going to have to dive into the internals. Good luck!